# Can't get an Awesomium render onto the screen in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, awesomium

I'm currently using [this](https://gist.github.com/2690490) code that someone recommended to combine [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) and XNA, however I'm having an issue... Whenever I try to draw the resulting Texture2d the component gives me, I get:

> You may not call SetData on a resource while it is actively set on the GraphicsDevice. Unset it from the device before calling SetData.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Awesomium.Core;

namespace ProjectTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        AwesomiumComponent uiHud;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500);
            uiHud = new AwesomiumComponent(this, rect);
            this.Components.Add(uiHud);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            uiHud.WebView.LoadURL("http://www.google.com/");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            //uiHud.Update(gameTime);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            Vector2 pos = new Vector2(10, 10);


            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(uiHud.WebViewTexture, pos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            //uiHud.Draw(gameTime);
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you should be drawing your hud with the spritebatch? It looks like the component itself has a `Draw` method exposed. Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: @Dervall I tried that, however I'm fairly sure that's not how it works. Plus nothing shows up when I do it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SpriteBatch` is setting the web texture into the graphics device's first texture stage and never unsetting it.  This is causing Awesomium's `Draw()` method to fail, because it's trying to call `SetData()` on a texture that's still in use.

After `spriteBatch.End()`, unset the texture stage:

```
GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
```

Comment: Wow that actually works... But is there a less hacky solution? Even editing the component. Your solution seems like it wouldn't work once I started working with a lot of textures, not to mention other possible issues(?)

Comment: The number of textures you're working with is irrelevant; there's only one texture stage involved.  You need to either unset that stage prior to the component's `Draw()` method being called, or _draw something with a different texture_ so that the texture is unset for you.  I suspect that the latter will turn out to be the more natural solution.

Comment: Just echoing Cole's comment that it's not hacky at all. Basically all rendering is achieved by setting various states on the graphics device, and then calling one of its `Draw` methods to actually trigger the drawing. `SpriteBatch` is literally doing `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = yourTexture` (and a bunch of other things) inside its easy-to-use wrapper.